# How can I get SQL Server to connect?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I've been trying to use SQL Server 2005, and I can't get it to do anything or even create a database, because every time I start it, I get a popup window that says "Connect to Server", and I can't connect to anything.  The "Server type" is "Database Engine", for "Authentication" I use "Windows authentication", but there's nothing available for the "Server name" list (I can also try "SQL Server Authentication" but I never had a chance to set up an account name or password when I installed, so I don't know what I'd type there).

I've canceled from that window and managed to create a server within the "Registered Servers" called "TEST", but it still doesn't appear on the "Server name" list in the "Connect to Server" popup window.  I can type in "TEST" manually (I've also tried "ADMIN:TEST" because I read somewhere that recommended that), but when I click the "Connect" button I get a popup window with an error that says:

> Cannot connect to TEST
>
> Additional Information:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1231)

I've seen that some people call it "localhost" or "(local)", so I tried both of these and in each case it said:

> Cannot connect to localhost.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Login failed for user -----. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

I also tried connecting to "127.0.0.1" but I just go the same long error as before, except that it said "error: 41" and "Error: 87", so only the numbers changed.

In any case, it always seems to keep thinking that I need to configure network settings or something, because if I go into the properties of the "TEST" server that I made, and into the "Connection Properties", it seems to want me to choose a "Network protocol" and related stuff.  I chose "Shared Memory", and then tried doing the same thing after clicking the "Options >>" button on the "Connect to Server" popup window.  I tried it with "localhost" and all that other stuff, but I keep getting the same errors.

Keep in mind that I'm doing all of this on a computer without an Internet connection and disabled network protocols (for better security), but I don't see why that would matter, because I'm not trying to connect to a web server, but just a "server" on my own computer.

Also, if I right-click on the "TEST" server and click "SQL Server Configuration Manager..." then I get an error that says:

Cannot connect to WMI provider.  You do not have permission or the server is unreachable.  Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager.  The RPC server is unavailable. [0x800706ba]

Please tell me how to get this to work so that I can run some queries.  I can actually write the queries but if I try to run them it just tries to make me connect to a server again, and I'm stuck in the same dead end.  So I hope someone can please help me.  Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server **2005** has been dead and buried for decades - you should ***REALLY*** urgently switch to a more recent version, e.g. 2017 or 2019 ......

Comment: Are you sure you installed SQL Server, and not just SSMS (the management software)? Which machine did you install it on? Do you actually have a machine named `TEST`, if not why are you trying to connect to it? Is the service started? Which version and edition is it? Is it the default instance or a named instance? If it's on a remote machine, is "allow remote connections" and TCP both enabled, and which port is it configure on? If the latter is SQL Browser service started?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: First of all, marc_s, the reason I'm using version 2005 is because it's the only one I have.  I've got it on CD, and while searching for a solution I found where I can get 2017, but it tries to download _while_ installing, which won't work, because like I said, the computer is offline.  Charlieface, I'll read that but meanwhile, TEST is the "registered server" that I made, all Internet protocols are disabled, it's Developer Edition 64-bit, I'm pretty sure I installed everything on the CD, it's on the same machine where I'm trying to use it, and I don't know answers to other questions.

Comment: I think maybe I should clarify what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm not connecting SQL Server to a website or even an application - I simply want to make a database and then manipulate tables and make diagrams, etc.  In fact, I only need it as a way of setting up stuff that I intend to reproduce in SQLite through a C++ program, but it's easier to do initially in SQL Server.  I'm already familiar with the interface but I just haven't used it in years, so I'm having trouble getting back into it.  That's all.  If someone can get me to where I can just use it simply in that way, it would be great!